# lets encrypt обновить

Tags: apache, ssl, letsencrypt

Обновляют вручную сертификат

```
certbot renew --force-renewal
```

В ответе получаю:

```
new certificate deployed with reload of nginx server; fullchain is
/etc/letsencrypt/live/sait.ru/fullchain.pem

Congratulations, all renewals succeeded. The following certs have been renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/sait.ru/fullchain.pem (success)
```

Через службы перезагружаю `httpd`.

ДАТА на сертификате не меняется . Что я упустил ?

Centos 7, Apache

Comment: В апаче путь к сертификату правильный прописан?

Comment: а где посмотреть это можно ?

Comment: Видимо, спросите того, кто настраивал letsencrypt в апаче?)

Comment: дайте развернутый ответ. Я сам его интегрировал через раздел модулей в ISP manager

Comment: Допишите в текст вопроса, что вы делали с ISP Manager, это очень важное дополнение